# ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLALchemy' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' error in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask and I am trying to learn `flask-sqlalchemy`. For that, I referred to their documentation: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

```
Here is my `__init__.py` file:

from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLALchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import routes
```

So, when I import the db variable with `from app import db` command, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\flask\tutorial\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Flask\tutorial\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLALchemy
ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLALchemy' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' (c:\users\dell\desktop\flask\tutorial\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py)
```

Why am I getting this error? I read through a few stack overflow questions, but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's `SQLAlchemy` not `SQLALchemy` - note the second `L` should be lowercase